# Can a message topic be subscribed on another topic?

Tags: message-queue, messaging

I have a suspicion the answer is "no", but I want to verify.

I have seen a similar question, where the responses were to tag messages to auto-forward, but this is not the same. Essentially, TopicA is at an enterprise level, and TopicB is at some local level. Local consumers will subscribe on TopicB, and TopicB will accept published messages/events, but I also want TopicB to now also get anything published on TopicA. So, there is no a priori awareness in the part of TopicA or publishers-to-TopicA that TopicB exists.

Right now, I'm thinking I'll need a small service to simply subscribe onto TopicA and publish to TopicB.

Answer (score 0):

What messaging implementation are you using?  If this is JMS, then look into using a message bridge.

Answer (score 0):

This is too generic of a question unfortunately.

In Kafka you could have a re-publisher that consumes from one stream and publishes to another.

In AMQP (e.g. RabbitMQ) you could have an exchange that's publishing both to global and local topic, doing the filtering on a routing key (or even a multi-level exchange topology).